# JQuery not working in IE

Tags: c#, jquery, html, codecharge

I am using the Tiny slideshow in my asp.net page. It works fine in all the Browser and here is the [LINK](http://www.spareach.com/%28X%281%29S%28denkrw45nvrq2vatpqk1gqaf%29%29/public/xtemp4.aspx?userid=22&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), But my problem starts when I include that page in my master page and display the same. the Jquery stop working in Internet explorer.

http://www.spareach.com/public/xtemp8.aspx?userid=22&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1

I am tired a lot for this.

Can any one help me please.

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't seem to work in Chrome or FF either. `TINY is not defined.`

Comment: Is it possible that your other browsers are using a cached version of some dependency? I'd try clearing your cache in FF and Chrome and seeing if it continues to work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your script interpreted by ASP.NET Session. the actual URL of file is  http://www.spareach.com/lightbox3/script.js. if you put the absolute URL then they work fine. hope this helpful

Comment: Thanks... thats works fine now... Actually now i have made the Iframe to runat server and assigned the path in Codebehind... Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1):

If you include that in another page, your relative link to the .js file is going to be invalid.  So, your options are to make it absolute (http://www.something.com/folder/tiny.js) or to include the .js from the head or common document, if you use that structure.

Comment: Won't prefixing with a forward slash suffice to point at the root? `/path/file.ext`

Comment: If you server configuration is setup with a base directory path, yes.  However, I've seen several that aren't setup correctly which can cause further confusion, which is why I didn't offer that suggestion.

Comment: I see; just thought I'd bring it into the mix.

Comment: But that working fine in Firefox. If thats the problem of relative URl then it wont even work in Firefox.